# How to extract the time HH: MM of a cell stored as "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I.E. `01/07/2011 09:30` I would like to extract `09:30` of this cell.

How I can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `=TEXT(cell, "hh:mm")` ([function help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it as a numeric value, so you can use it for calculations

=mod(A1,1)

Format as time.

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
```

This will be formatted as a time value automatically.